# Can anyone explain to me how the supernova in BSG was supposed to help the Colonials?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

I'm realizing that I never truly understood this back when the show was running.

So with the help of Baltar's notes on a bunch of star charts, by the end of Season 3, the Colonials are making progress with finding their way to Earth. At some point in Season 3, they stumble upon a planet with lots of algae they can collect for food, right? But what exactly did the supernova visible from that planet tell the Colonials in relation to Earth? How was it useful in getting the Colonials to the Ionian Nebula at the end of Season 3?

Answer (score 7):

**In cosmology, certain kinds of [nova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova), [pulsars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar), [supernova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova) and their resultant [nebula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebula) can act as cosmic landmarks if a viewer can tell how far away a nova/nebula is and how long ago the supernova took place.** *[See: Stellar Parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax#Stellar_parallax)*

- Since light has a fixed speed, if you can calculate distances from different locations, you could concievably use the nova as a cosmic marker to another location.
- Other cosmic markers include quasars which are extremely distant stellar objects whose movement is relatively fixed by their incredible distance. They are able to be used no matter where one is in a particular galaxy.
- In the BSG storyline the [Ionian Nebula](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Ionian_Nebula) resembled a nebula which was seen from the planet of origin of the 13 Tribes of Kobal. It was considered a landmark used to find certain nearby star systems including Earth.

**From the BSG Wiki**

> - The Ionian Nebula is a supernova remnant located approximately 13,000 light years distant from the algae planet.
> - In their search for the [Eye of Jupiter's](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Eye_of_Jupiter) purpose and symbolism, Lieutenant Gaeta discovers that a nova occurred in the Ionian system which would have been observed 4,000 years ago on ancient Kobol, around the time of the [Thirteenth Tribe's exodus](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Thirteenth_Tribe_%28RDM%29). The timing of the nova with the Thirteenth Tribe's journey and its resemblance to the algae planet system's nova suggests to Gaeta that the Tribe's next marker is the Ionian Nebula (Rapture).

[image: Ionian Nebula]

*Ionian Nebula*

Comment: Okay, that's pretty helpful, thank you. But I'm still confused on one detail, probably because I don't understand this kind of science all that well. I can see how the Nebula is a pointer to Earth, if it is described in the scrolls and can be seen from Kobol. But why would the star going nova on the algae planet necessarily point Gaeta towards the Ionian Nebula? What does one have to do with the other, even if both supernovas were similar (and I'm not even sure what that would mean)?

Comment: So, while trying to edit my own question, I think I may have accidentally erased one of your comments here. If you come back and find this to be true, please know it was an accident and not me being horribly rude. I've edited my own question with a followup question, should you care to weigh in. Thanks. :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the nova on the algae planet was supposed to serve as a marker by activating the temple leading to the next crumb in the trail toward finding Earth. With so much predestination and other "near-mysticism" at this point in the series, I found it hard to call it science fiction because events take place without a clear cause, knowledge is possessed without a reasonable source for that information. Your confusion is to be expected. I certainly was. (That expression, "Making it up as they go along" certainly comes to mind, doesn't it?)